# Help me with tag in homepage head

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

I'm having a lot of problems adding an html tag in head section only on homepage layout (that's defined in my custom theme as page layout). I'm using M2 v. 2.2

In **default.xml** is defined

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.fonts" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/fonts.phtml" after="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
</referenceBlock>
```

and I added a block to edit and insert an html tag:

```
<referenceBlock name="head.additional">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.fonts" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/fonts.phtml" after="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.metas" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/metas.phtml" before="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
</referenceBlock>
```

so that I would be able to change the phtml template inside the home xml page layout but if I reference the block it doesn't change.

Any help? I'm on this from 2 days and it driving me crazy. THANKS

Comment: Did you tried with cms_index_index.xml layout file.

Comment: @SumitVerma I want the tag only on the homepage layout. I use that layout to add and remove content on the page and those other rules are working fine (like inserting or moving containers)

Comment: Can you please share block code in question

Comment: the metas.phtml is empty, I've tried inserting a comment and it's showing, but I need to show a custom tag only on the home layout

Comment: can you suggest an other way to insert a custom html tag inside the head section in a custom layout xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use `<referenceBlock name="head.additional">` in **default.xml**. Because it's the place to define `head.additional` by default. Instead, if you want to show it on homepage only, you should place your code on **cms_index_index.xml**. So that:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.fonts" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/fonts.phtml" after="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Put these code into `app/design/frontend/<Vendor_Name>/<Theme_Name>/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml`. Then clear cache and refresh. Your block should appear.

Comment: My savior!!!! Thanks a lot!
as for <referenceBlock name="head.additional"> in default.xml it was already there...I'm defining a custom child theme. Anyway THANKS <3

Comment: *the body closure has to be </body>

Answer (score 1):

Create New `cms_index_index.xml` under your theme.

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Magento_Cms/layout/cms_index_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="head.additional">
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.fonts" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/fonts.phtml" after="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
             <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="head.additional.metas" template="Infortis_Base::html/header/metas.phtml" before="head.additional.asset-wrapper" />
        </referenceContainer>
    <body/>
</page>
```

Comment: Exactly, the previous answer was right just the path it was in Magento_Cms and not Magento_Theme. Thanks

Comment: If my answer working fine vote and accept

Comment: Me go first so my answer is accepted. Upvote for you still. XD.